# jQuery's each loop

Tags: jquery, load, each

I'm stuck with understanding a behaviour of my each loop.

Here's my code:

```
$.each(thumbs, function() {    // where thumbs is array of strings
    project = this;

    $('#gallery').append(
        '<li>'
      + '<a href="/portfolio/' + project + '">'
      + '<img src="/img/' + project + '_bw.jpg" id="' + project + '_bw" />'
      + '<img src="/img/' + project + '_tn.jpg" id="' + project + '_tn" />'
      + '</a>'
      + '</li>'
    );

    // alert(project); - alerts every element of array as expected

    $('#' + project + '_bw').load(function() {

        // alert(project); - alerts only the last element of array, 
        // but as many times as many elements in array

        $('#' + project + '_bw').fadeIn(150,function(){
            $('#' + project + '_tn').css("opacity", 1);
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is, that when I'm trying to define id of the element, where I want to execute .load function it attaches this function only to the last element of array which I'm looping through.

Comment: you need to put your load in an external function and pass project as argument and call the function in the loop (see scope)

Comment: Hi 3dgoo, sure. It's array of strings: "proja", "projb", "projc"

Comment: your load do not have time to finish that the loop as finish all the iterations, to make sure each loop trigger one unique load do as I described above

Comment: Hi @JonathandeM. Thank you for your reply. I took your advise and put the load as an external function and it works, but I still can't understand why it didn't work inside the scope as the id for the load function was defined before the loop ended so, before changed the element of "thumbs".

Comment: your load is overwriten for every iteration of the loop, if you set a function each call of the function will create a scope for each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the scope of `project` is defined outside of your each loop.

So all the `thumbs` are looped through, and the load listeners are set. But by the time the first load event is called and the load listener function is called, the `project` variable is set to the last value of the loop.

So what you need to do is set a local variable inside the each loop to set the variable for each iteration.

Try this:

**Javascript**

```
$.each(thumbs, function () {
    var thisProject = this;

    $('#gallery').append(
        '<li>' + '<a href="/portfolio/' + thisProject + '"><img src="/img/' + thisProject + '_bw.jpg" id="' + thisProject + '_bw" /><img src="/img/' + thisProject + '_tn.jpg" id="' + thisProject + '_tn" /></a></li>');

    $('#' + thisProject + '_bw').load(function () {
        $('#' + thisProject + '_bw').fadeIn(150, function () {
            $('#' + thisProject + '_tn').css("opacity", 1);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is an example of the problem:

**HTML**

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var count = 0;
$.each([500,1000,1500,2000,2500], function() {
    var thisValue = this;
    var inScopeCount = count + 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#output').append('<strong>For ' + thisValue + ':</strong><br />count: ' + count + '<br /> inScopeCount: ' + inScopeCount + '<br />');
    }, this);
    count += 1;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wdbN/)**

Comment: Hi @3dgoo, thanks for your comments, I'm not sure if this is a result of late working hours, but I can't see any difference between your "try this" code and mine. Please note my variable "project" is defined within ".each" function, the same way yours var "thisProject". Am I missing something?

Comment: The difference is declaring it with `var` inside the for each. This will create the variable for this instance of the loop. The demo shows the difference. Have a look once jsfiddle is back up and running.